# Taking a Picture and Saving the Photo to a Directory within the Crossplatform App

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to using Xamarin Forms. I want to create the functionality for a multi-platform app of taking a picture and saving the photo to a directory within the crossplatform app. Does anyone know how I would do this? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaPicker Plugin for Xamarin.Forms